# Give the name of customers who bought ALL products with price less than 5

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, relational-division, northwind

I want to write a query that give names of those customers only who have bought all products whose price is less than 5. Whereas, my query gives all customers who have bought even a single product whose price is less than 5.

```
SELECT Customers.CompanyName AS Customers
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
JOIN [Order Details]
ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
JOIN Products
ON Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID
WHERE [Order Details].ProductID  IN (
  SELECT Products.ProductID FROM Products WHERE Products.UnitPrice < 5
)
```

Comment: add exists.......

Comment: Provide a minimal running example with data.

Comment: On your last line, try putting `1=1 AND` after `WHERE` and you should get a condition that requires all of the instances to be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT Customers.CompanyName AS Customers
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
JOIN [Order Details]
ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
JOIN Products
ON Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID
WHERE [Order Details].ProductID  IN (
  SELECT Products.ProductID FROM Products WHERE Products.UnitPrice < 5)
GROUP BY CompanyName 
HAVING COUNT([Order Details].ProductID) = (SELECT Count(Products.ProductID) FROM Products WHERE Products.UnitPrice < 5)
```

I Included the GROUP BY and Having Clause so that you can get only the customers who have bought all the products with unit price less than 5

Comment: This query is giving error: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: Just tested this on the northwind database and it works, made an edit to fix a ) that was omitted

Comment: I fixed that bracket ')' problem and after that i encountered the above error  'Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference'.